# Prove that $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2$ are relatively prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and not both odd, prove that $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2$ are also relatively prime.

Comment: False. Eg $a=3,b=5$

Comment: in fact parity shows any time both $a,b$ are odd, both expressions are even.

Comment: Truth. a,b even then?

Comment: $a,b$ even means they aren't coprime.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I forgot to include not both odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct result is that $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2$ are relatively prime unless $a$ and $b$ are both odd.

If $a$ and $b$ are both odd, then  $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2$ have g.c.d. $2$.

N.B. Any common divisor of  $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2$ must divide both their sum, $2a^2$ and their difference, $2b^2$. Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime the only possibilities for the g.c.d. are $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Can you prove the amended statement? It's not obvious and this isn't a complete answer without that.

Comment: Thanks - I've added to the answer.

Comment: Corrected the question

Comment: @MattSamuel gcd must divide $2b^2$ so it's either 2, or a factor of $b^2$ but those can't divide $a^2$ proof complete.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

The statement is invalid.

Let $a=x^2-1$ and $b=2x$. $$\begin{align} a^2+b^2 &=(x^2+1)^2 \\ a^2-b^2 &=(x^2-2x-1)(x^2+2x+1).\end{align}$$ When $x$ is odd, they have a common factor of $2$.

---

Whoops, didn't realise the question was edited until after.

Comment: When x is odd, a and b are both even

Comment: @Truth-seek I didn't see the OP's edit. Apologies.